# Click event function not being fired from inside Fancybox lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using fancybox http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ to add a lightbox popup to my site. I have also added a link under the lightbox pop out image, and am trying to change other things on the page.

If I put the click function into jsfiddle it works just fine :

http://jsfiddle.net/cmVjN/

but when it is clicked from inside the lightbox the click event function isnt triggered :

```
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox-thumb").fancybox({
             afterLoad: function() {
            this.title = '<a class="selectlink" href="#" id="' + this.title + '">Select This Image</a> ';
        },
            prevEffect  : 'none',
            nextEffect  : 'none',
            helpers : {

                title   : {
                    type: 'outside'
                },
                thumbs  : {
                    width   : 50,
                    height  : 50
                }
            }

        });


    $('.selectlink').click(function () {
        var myId = $(this.id);
        alert(this.id);
        $('#' + myId).prop('checked', true);
    });
    });
    </script>
```

This is the html / php

```
echo '<div class="imagewrapper">';
echo '<a title="'.$row2['id'].'" class="fancybox-thumb" rel="fancybox-thumb" href="albums/'.$albumid.'/800x600/'.$row2['image'].'"><img style="border-radius:5px;" src="albums/'.$albumid.'/thumbnails/'.$row2['image'].'" /></a>';
  echo '<div style="text-align:center;">';
  echo '<strong>Select : </strong><input class="selectcheckbox" type="checkbox" name="'.$row2['image'].'" id="'.$row2['id'].'" />';
  echo '</div>';
  echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Delegate event `$(this).on('click','.selectlink',function () {...});` Here 'this' refers to document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).on('click', '.selectlink', function () {
     var myId = $(this.id);
     alert(this.id);
     $('#' + myId).prop('checked', true);
});
```

Basically what happens is the element is not loaded when you set the event handler, but using `.on` will delegate event from document to the required element. so the elements that will be added in future also will fire the event.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thanks !, that is alerting me now, but its not checking the checkbox still

Comment: By the way the check box shares the same id as the link

Comment: you cannot have two elements with the same id on the same page. you can append some kind of a string before, if you want, #chkbox_myid or something like this.

Comment: Ok I have changed the checkbox id to <input class="selectcheckbox" type="checkbox" name="'.$row2['image'].'" id="check_'.$row2['id'].'" />';

Comment: and jquery to : $('#check_' + myId).prop('checked', true);

Comment: but its still not checking the checkbox ?

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: If I use this I get in the alert [object Object]
$(document).on('click', '.selectlink', function () {
     var myId = $('check_' + this.id);
     alert(myId);
     $(myId).prop('checked', true);
});

Comment: Ensure that the code is not inserted inside of a $(document).ready( [...] ) block of code. For me, this prevented my click event capture code from working.

Answer (score 0):

I got there in the end with :

```
$(document).on('click', '.selectlink', function () {
 var myId = $('#check_' + this.id);
 $(myId).attr('checked', true);
 countChecked();
```